# Where is HDMI2 output in Mi Notebook pro i7/16gb?

Tags: linux, display, multiple-monitors, hdmi, xrandr

I've [Mi Notebook pro i7/16gb](https://www.amazon.de/-/en/Xiaomi-Notebook-i7-CPU-DDR4-RAM-GeForce/dp/B079XX2FLF).

Now I can connect 2 external monitors via HDMI1 and DP1 outputs.

```sh
$ xrandr
eDP1 connected primary 1920x1080+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 340mm x 190mm
   1920x1080     60.03*+  59.93    48.00  
DP1 connected 3840x2160+3840+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 630mm x 360mm
   3840x2160     60.00*+  30.00    29.97  
HDMI1 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 530mm x 300mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+  50.00    59.94  
HDMI2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

So:

- eDP1: my laptop's monitor
- HDMI1: HDMI port
- DP1: the first USB-C port

But I've no idea what the HDMI2 is and where it is.
Second usb-c port does nothing when it connected in any way to a monitor.

There're also 2 usb-a ports and they don't work with monitors as well. And also there're audio jack and card reader.

Is HDMI2 really exist?
I've tried to google it, but I couldn't find anything more than I already know.

Comment: It is entirely possible that it shows up because it is a part of your onboard GPU, but is not physically wired up to anywhere.

Comment: @Mokubai yes it's possible, thanks